# Transition delay for links is more than the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a custom javascript function, I remove **my-content-section-visible** and add **my-content-section-hidden** class to disappear the div with a **transition**.

This transition works as intended. But the cursor still detects the links in the content for 2-3 seconds more after the div is totally invisible. This might be confusing for the end user.

What would be the reason for this? Can I use other style than "visibility:" for less problem? AFAIK display doesn't work in this condition.

```
.my-content-section-visible{
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms; 
    transition-duration: 400ms;
    /* Several other styles here */
}

.my-content-section-hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. I disable the link action.

```
.my-content-section-hidden a{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try to affects the contents in container too?

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ebyptvt6/

example css:

```
.container {
  /* css code */
}
.container:hover, .container:hover .contents {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```